# Dynamically insert an Enum Type as argument in a class constructor expecting <TEnum>

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, types, enums

I am trying to create a generic mapping function for GraphQL.NET. Here is the sample enum I'm using:

```
    public enum ForcePower
    {
        Throw,
        Pull,
        Choke,
        Lightning
    }

    public class Jedi 
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string HomePlanet { get; set; }
        public ForcePower Power { get; set; }        
    }
```

currently, the enum has to be passed in explicitly:

```
        object obj = new Jedi();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {                
            var isEnum = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo().BaseType == typeof(Enum);

            if (isEnum)
            {
                var enumType = typeof(EnumerationGraphType<ForcePower>);
                Field(type: enumType, name: propertyInfo.Name, description: description);
            }

        }
```

Can 'ForcePower' be passed in dynamically?

Comment: I am not sure I even follow what you are doing here.  Why is the `obj` variable type `object` and not `Jedi`?  What is all this reflection supposed to be doing?  Why is reflection needed?  I think this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  You should explain to us in simple terms (i.e not programming concepts) what you want to achieve

Comment: You can use generics.

Comment: @maccettura - I suppose in this case Jedi could be used instead of object, but my goal is to create something that would eventually be used for any object. Essentially I want to pass 'ForcePower' or any other Enum directly, i.e can I achieve var enumType = typeof(EnumerationGraph<[AnyEnumHere]>).  

I'm having some sort of mental disconnect I'm sure, and open to suggestions. Should I provide more detailed code?

Comment: @maccettura updated the code, hopefully a little more clear. Essentially I don't want to hardcode 'ForcePower' so I can pass in any enum that could exist in the Jedi class.

Comment: @rahotimus I still dont understand what you are asking.  If a Jedi class has a ForcePower property then of course you need to assign it some value.